# Redirect to freshdesk.com from Salesforce.com

Tags: visualforce, redirect, external-app

I am trying to redirect to Freshdesk.com from Visualforce link.

I have Name,Email and Hashcode to redirect and login to the freshdesk.com

```
http://sample.freshdesk.com/?name=Arun+Bhatia&email=Arun.bhatia%40xxx.com&hash=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Please help as I am not able to successfully login.

```
  public with sharing class DOTSCtrl {
   public string getSsoUrl()
    {
        string secert = '3dfcb482a6eb25148beb';
        string name = 'Arun+Support'; //UserInfo.getUserName();
        string email = 'arun@gmail.com'; //UserInfo.getUserEmail();
        String baseUrl= 'http://support.max.com/login/sso/?name='+name +'&email='+email+'&hash='+getHash(secert,name,email);
        String[] arguments = new String[] {baseUrl, EncodingUtil.urlEncode(name,'UTF-8'),
                             EncodingUtil.urlEncode(email,'UTF-8'), GetHash(secert, name, email)};

        return String.Format(baseUrl, arguments );
    }
    static string GetHash(string secert, string name, string email)
    {
     string input = name + secert + email;  // New Format : Order of passing arguments changed at freshdesk end in reference to security updates.
     system.debug('arun-----'+input);
     input = input.toLowerCase();
     system.debug('arun-----'+input);
       string hash = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', Blob.valueOf(input)));
      system.debug('arun-----'+hash);
       return hash ;
    }


}
```

Please note the hashcode that i am generating is wrong.

Comment: Might that link need to be https?

Comment: Can you provide more code from the actual VF page? Would be helpful to see the controller code behind the PageReference. I assume you are attempting to setup a single sign on?

Comment: add the code in original message.